# TYPO3 fluid translations not works on mail templates

Tags: typo3

Hello everybody ) I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18, and in my fluid mail templates translations not works.
That's is code in my controller which rendering mail template:

```
$emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');

        $ext_path = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath("feusersplus");
        $templatePathAndFilename =  $ext_path.'Resources/Private/Mail/Admin/updateInfo.html';
        $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);
        $emailView->assignMultiple(
            array(
                'hash' => $hash,
                'userDetailPid' => $userDetailPid,
                'userUid' => $user->getUid(),
                'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                'image' => $userValues['image'],
                'aboutmyself' => $userValues['aboutmyself'],
                'aboutmypartner' => $userValues['aboutmypartner'],
                'aboutmyselfSeconduser' => $this->pluginVariables['aboutmyselfSeconduser'],
                'aboutmypartnerSeconduser' => $this->pluginVariables['aboutmypartnerSeconduser'],
                'imprint' => $this->extConf['address'],
                'backgroundimage' => $up->getBackgroundimage(),
                'uploadFolder' => FileUtility::getUploadFolderFromTca()
            )
        );
        $emailBody = $emailView->render();

        $message = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
        $message->setTo($adminemail)
            ->setFrom(array($adminemail => $this->extConf['mailtitle']))
            ->setSubject( \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('request_to_update_profile', 'feusersplus'));
        $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');
        $message->send();
```

That's is small part from fluid

```
 <table class="twelve columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td><h1><f:translate key='want_to_update_profile_information'/></h1></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><p><f:translate key='user'/> {username} <f:translate key='want_to_update_profile_information'/><br>
                              <f:translate key='image'/>: {image} <br>
                              <img src="http://abenteuertreff.ihr-layout.eu/fileadmin/files/Avatars/{image}" width="30%" height="auto"/><br>
                              <f:translate key='backgroundimage'/>: <br>
                              <f:image image="{backgroundimage}" absolute="true"/><br>

  <br>
                            </p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <p><f:translate key='about_myself'/>: {aboutmyself} <br>
                                <f:translate key='about_my_partner'/>: {aboutmypartner} <br>
                                <f:translate key='about_myself'/> (<f:translate key='second_user'/>): {aboutmyselfSeconduser} <br>
                                <f:translate key='about_my_partner'/> (<f:translate key='second_user'/>): {aboutmypartnerSeconduser}</p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <f:link.action pageUid="{userDetailPid}" absolute="true" arguments="{showUid: userUid}" additionalParams="{updateHash: hash}" extensionName="feuserfriends" pluginName="userlist" controller="Friend">
                                <f:translate key='accept'/> accept
</f:link.action>
<br />
<br />
<hr />
</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
```

Help me please )

Comment: Can you also post (at least a part of) your template where you expect a translation?

Comment: I updated my post ) help please )

Comment: Please also add WHERE your code takes place. Is it a frontend plugin, backend module or a scheduler task/command line?

Comment: It's view of plugin of my extension. In other fluid templates translations works good, but in mail not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$emailView->getRequest()->setPluginName($requestPluginName);
$emailView->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName($requestControllerExtensionName);
$emailView->getRequest()->setControllerName($requestControllerName);
$emailView->getRequest()->setControllerActionName($requestControllerActionName);

// if you have an extbase controller context you can set it too
$emailView->setControllerContext(...)
```

At least the ControllerExtensionName should be set, then the f:translate works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't pass any ControllerContext to the view, but use

```
   /**
    * @param array $recipient recipient of the email in the format array('recipient@domain.tld' => 'Recipient Name')
    * @param array $sender sender of the email in the format array('sender@domain.tld' => 'Sender Name')
    * @param string $subject subject of the email
    * @param string $templateName template name (UpperCamelCase)
    * @param array $variables variables to be passed to the Fluid view
    */
    protected function sendTemplateEmail(array $recipient, array $sender, $subject, $templateName, array $variables = array()) {
      /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView $emailView */
      $emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');

      $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
      $emailRootPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPaths'][1]);

      $templatePathAndFilename = $emailRootPath . 'Emails/' . $templateName . '.html';

      $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);
      $emailView->assignMultiple($variables);
      $emailBody = $emailView->render();

      /** @var $message \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage */
      $message = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
      $message->setTo($recipient)
          ->setFrom($sender)
          ->setSubject($subject);

      // Plain text example
      // $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/plain');

      // HTML Email
      $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');

      $message->send();
      return $message->isSent();
    }
```

and in the corresponding Fluid-Template

`{f:translate(key: "want_to_update_profile_information", extensionName: "EXTENSIONKEY")}`

`$variables`in the controller is an PHP-array with needed key-valu-pairs for the fluid-Template of the E-Mail.

Of course the code has to be adapted where ever needed... (Template-Path and so on)

Comment: it's just rather cumbersome to put the extension name in the template all the time. That's where the setters are really helpful.